# Get data using group row conditions

Tags: mysql

Users Table

```
|user_id |   user_email  |
|1       | xyz@mail.com  |
|2       | abc@mail.com  |
```

Relations Table

```
id | user_id | user_type |   action   |
1  | 1       | 1         |  Sign      |
2  | 1       | 2         |  Waiting   |
1  | 2       | 1         |  Sign      |
2  | 2       | 2         |  Sign      |
```

I want to get Data which user_type = 1 and action = sign but user_type = 2 and action is not sign for the same user_id.

So output looks like

```
id |    email     | user_id | user_type |   action   |
2  | xyz@mail.com | 1       | 2         |  Waiting   |
```

Here is what i did as per my knowlege.

```
SELECT * FROM relations WHERE (
    CASE
        WHEN user_type = 1 AND action = 'Sign'
        THEN user_type = 2 AND action != 'Sign'
    END
) GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: Can you add the output you want?

Comment: @dmg sorry dear i added what i try. what i want is help of some export who help me to lear things like this.

Comment: @Zakaria added expected output.

Comment: Is your data representative ? for example is sign>>waiting>>sign possible if so what should happen?

Comment: FYI *case* is an expression, it's not a control-of-flow statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select r.id, u.user_email, r.user_id, r.user_type, r.action
from relations r inner join users u on r.user_id = u.user_id
where action <> 'Sign' and exists (select id from relations where user_id = r.user_id and action = 'Sign')
```

Basically check for each row where action is different of sign if there is a row with the same user_id where the action is sign. Join The two tables to get the email.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=063d8f400cf5b5af0016fceae2c3261a)